# Transfer a big app web2py to a new server

Tags: python, web2py

I would like to transfer an app from server 1 to server 2 (size of the app 700Mb)
first test : try to pack to build a w2p package --> internal error  (it works for app 400 Mb)
Second test : i create a tar from server 1 and i transfer to server 2 --> the app tells me no function (note that she works very well on server 1)

Server 1 : debian jessie
Server 2 : debian buster

Any idea ?

thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To transfer big apps, I do the following: Go to "applications" folder in web2py of serverv1, then zip your app,  then move it through SSH or other method to the new server, and place it in the "applications" folder of web2py of server 2. Reload routes in web2py admin app. I haven't experienced troubles with this method.

Reload the routes , thank you to Christin varas : https://groups.google.com/d/msg/web2py/05Ftfd9i404/eLGOt64FBAAJ

Answer (score 0):

what i would suggest is compile the app and then transfer however you would like to another server. that will solve 700mb issue and keeps integrity of app files.